# What is the difference between a windowing system and a window manager?

Tags: x11, window-manager, compiz, wayland

What is the difference between a windowing system (for example X11, Wayland) and a window manager (Awesome, Compiz, OpenBox)?

Comment: Maybe this help: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuUbu.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you refer to as a windowing system is more commonly referred to as a [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server).

The differences between display servers are well documented. But, the difference between a display server and a window manager is in the job that they perform. A display server handles displaying graphical applications and relaying input and output from graphical applications to the rest of the system and vice versa.

On the other hand, a window manager's job is to manage how (or more often, where) the display server displays its client windows.

As a result, almost no one uses a display server without using a window manager of some kind (though it is possible). You can more simply think of this relationship like so: The display server displays everything graphpical, and the window manager organizes the client windows for display by the display server.

Comment: According to wikipedia, a windowing system and a display server are to different things. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windowing_system

Comment: No, those articles show that a window manager and a windowing system are different; but a windowing system is synonymous with a display server (with, perhaps, one technicality being that a window system is the whole framework, and the display server is what actually displays things).

Comment: Sorry, I meant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windowing_system, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server

Comment: No worries. But that article still supports what I said. The Window System (which includes the display server) manages graphical displays. The window manager organizes graphical clients for display by the display server.